# trouble combining geom_rect and facet_grid in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to shade part of the background in each facet of a simple plot.  If I omit faceting and run geom_rect + geom_point, the expected results appear as shown in the MRE below.  If I omit the rectangle and run geom_point + facet_grid, the expected 4 panels have each point in the correct facet.  But when I combine geom_rect + geom_point + and facet_grid, the points in the first category and only those get plotted in every facet.  What is going on please???

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(42)
syn.dat <- data.frame(
   category.1 = as.factor(rep(c("1A", "1B"), each = 8)),
   category.2 = as.factor(rep(rep(c("2A", "2B"), times = 2), each = 4)),
   x = rep(-1:2, each = 4) + runif(8, max = .4),
   y = rep(-1:2, each = 4) + runif(8, max = .4))

ggplot() +
   geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = .5, 
      ymax = Inf), fill = "lightyellow") +
   geom_point(data = syn.dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
   facet_grid(cols = vars(category.1), 
      rows = vars(category.2))
```

[image: Works without facets]

[image: Works without rectangle]

[image: Fails with both]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure about this, but it may be that you need to explicitly provide the `data` argument to `ggplot` itself, in order for `facet_grid` to correctly pick up all the values?

```
ggplot(syn.dat) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = 0.5, ymax = Inf), fill = "lightyellow") +
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    facet_grid(rows = vars(category.2), vars(cols = category.1))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!  I've NO idea why this is necessary with geom_rect but not with geom_abline or geom_vline. 
 But when I put your idea in my full code it fixes the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: Expanding a bit, the `geom_rect()` layer needs *any* data.frame with >= 1 row for the facetting to  work (directly in the layer or inheriting from the global data). I have no idea why this get's evaluated so weirdly, but for OP's use case it seems like `annotate(..., geom = "rect")` would be the typical solution to the problem.

Comment: I've run into the same issue today as OP. My use case is a bit trickers as I want to supply a vector to `geom_rect()`. Using the same approach rectangle appear as they should, but the facets all show the same data (same as OP). Using `geom_rect()` and setting `data` in `ggplot()` I get `"! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (347)"`. Using `annotate()`, I get `"! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (84)"`. Most of all, I don't understand why I can't just pass a vector to `annotate(geom="rect", ...)`. @teunbrand Do you happen to have a solution?